# Create maven package

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I am sorry but I am a complete noob on using maven. There is this .api library that I am trying to get updated and I just can't seem to grasp my head around maven at all.

On this [site](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/download)

It states to do a **‘mvn package’**

Then add in the dependency and repositories.

Excuse me if I did this wrong as being that this was my first time.

With *Eclipse* I tried to create a maven project and select the downloaded folder as my location. Add in the dependency and repository. That failed miserably :( there were no errors but nothing happened on my eclipse. I tried to go maven > download sources. I get this warning*:

> "There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly
>   compatible with this environment."

So without further ado I tried the basics of learning using maven on eclipse installing maven and merging it with eclipse. However the problem "Do a maven package" in which I then understood the basics but I still don't get it. How do you create a maven package within the project downloaded? if it was meant to be done that way...

I also tried just getting the updated source code and adding it to my project as a jar but the problem still persist since the source code requires items inside of it other than the jars it requested.(Less memory over the older version)

Now to my question:

1. How do you create a maven project which then updates the project?
2. Would it be better if I did the changes on Console of msdos or by eclipse?
3. Can someone help me on doing this?(My mind is completely blown!)

Comment: Well* at least I am getting some traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1 : How do you create a maven project which then updates the project**
I don't understand what you mean. Could you be more explicit please ?

**Question 2 : Would it be better if I did the changes on Console of msdos or by eclipse**

For further uses, prefer maven in command line (this is closer to system and don't have any overlaying API). Moreover, it will learn you more things.

I was facing issues using eclipse integreted tools, that was not present in command line.

**Question 3 : Can someone help me on doing this?(My mind is completely blown!)**
Did you tried to fill JAVA_HOME system variable ? For instance : 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\

- Which version or Maven are you using ?
- Which version of Java are you using ?
- Which version of Java are you using for running Eclipse  (edit eclipse/eclipse.ini (if there nothing about it, it will use your default JVM defined in system variables) ?

Maven 3 require at least JRE 1.5 (1.6 is more often used).

More information here : http://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html

---

From the Maven Documentation :

> Maven is a Java tool, so you must have Java installed in order to proceed. More precisely, you need a Java Development Kit (JDK), the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is not sufficient.
>
> Additional optional installation steps are listed after the platform specific instructions.
>
> Windows 2000/XP
>
> - Unzip the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4. These instructions assume you chose C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation. The subdirectory apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive.
> - Add the M2_HOME environment variable by opening up the system properties (WinKey + Pause), selecting the "Advanced" tab, and the "Environment Variables" button, then adding the M2_HOME variable in the user variables with the value C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4. Be sure to omit any quotation marks around the path even if it contains spaces. Note: For Maven < 2.0.9, also be sure that the M2_HOME doesn't have a '\' as last character.
> - In the same dialog, add the M2 environment variable in the user variables with the value %M2_HOME%\bin.
> - Optional: In the same dialog, add the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable in the user variables to specify JVM properties, e.g. the value -Xms256m -Xmx512m. This environment variable can be used to supply extra options to Maven.
> - In the same dialog, update/create the Path environment variable in the user variables and prepend the value %M2% to add Maven available in the command line.
> - **In the same dialog, make sure that JAVA_HOME exists in your user variables or in the system variables and it is set to the location of your JDK, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_02 and that %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in your Path environment variable.**
>
> Open a new command prompt (Winkey + R then type cmd) and run mvn --version to verify that it is correctly installed.

Comment: Question 1: To further elaborate I have no idea whether you create a maven project and then it just automatically updates the new jars for the system.

Comment: Question 3: Yes, I have fully installed Maven but I would like it if I have a step by step procedure to "Install source jars"

Comment: If you are new to Maven, please, read this book : www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/. What do you mean by "Install source jars" ? Like installing Apache HTTP server from sources ? Or create a maven project "From existing sources" ?

Comment: There is a book? Oh my god That would help a lot.

Comment: I just got to 23 today because I added a newer question would have voted up.